# Ordering Cycle - FirewallD & DBusException

Tags: linux, systemd, d-bus, firewalld

[SYSTEM]

Virgin DigitalOcean droplet Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-52-generic x86_64) with all updates
with latest Virtualmin and nothing else.

How would you suggest I proceed with this?

[PROBLEM] 
After a reboot, 30% of the times, the D-Bus & FirewallD will fail like so:

```
Jun 20 09:28:35 ns1 networkd-dispatcher[679]: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.FileNotFound: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory 
Jun 20 09:28:35 ns1 systemd[1]: networkd-dispatcher.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Jun 20 09:28:35 ns1 systemd[1]: networkd-dispatcher.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. 
Jun 20 09:28:35 ns1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.
```

Contrast this with the times it succeeds:

```
Jun 20 09:30:16 ns1 networkd-dispatcher[678]: No valid path found for iwconfig
Jun 20 09:30:16 ns1 networkd-dispatcher[678]: No valid path found for iw 
Jun 20 09:30:16 ns1 networkd-dispatcher[678]: WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete. 
Jun 20 09:30:16 ns1 systemd[1]: Started Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd. 
Jun 20 09:30:16 ns1 systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
```

[BACKGROUND] 
'Networkd-dispatcher is a dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd connection status changes.... The daemon listens for signals from systemd-networkd over dbus'

[THEORY] 
So DBus does not start and networkd-dispatcher.service depends on it to service signals... 
When 'Failed to start Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.', firewalld croaks and maybe other things I guess.

[PATTERN] 
I have noticed a pattern that happens when these failures occurs.

```
[FirewallD reports:] Failed to list zones : Error: DBUS_ERROR: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
Jun 21 05:54:11 ns1 kernel: [ 8.398419] systemd[1]: firewalld.service: Found ordering cycle on dbus.socket/start
Jun 21 05:54:11 ns1 kernel: [ 8.404282] systemd[1]: firewalld.service: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
Jun 21 05:54:11 ns1 kernel: [ 8.424332] systemd[1]: firewalld.service: Found dependency on cloud-init.service/start
Jun 21 05:54:11 ns1 kernel: [ 8.438320] systemd[1]: firewalld.service: Found dependency on systemd-networkd-wait-online.service/start
Jun 21 05:54:11 ns1 kernel: [ 8.497168] systemd[1]: firewalld.service: Found dependency on systemd-networkd.service/start
Jun 21 05:54:11 ns1 kernel: [ 8.505811] systemd[1]: firewalld.service: Found dependency on network-pre.target/start

[FirewallD reports:] Failed to list zones : FirewallD is not running
Jun 21 05:44:39 ns1 kernel: [ 7.396133] systemd[1]: network-pre.target: Found ordering cycle on firewalld.service/stop
Jun 21 05:44:39 ns1 kernel: [ 7.408784] systemd[1]: network-pre.target: Found dependency on basic.target/start
Jun 21 05:44:39 ns1 kernel: [ 7.418770] systemd[1]: network-pre.target: Found dependency on sockets.target/start
Jun 21 05:44:39 ns1 kernel: [ 7.455484] systemd[1]: network-pre.target: Found dependency on lxd.socket/start
Jun 21 05:44:39 ns1 kernel: [ 7.470305] systemd[1]: network-pre.target: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
Jun 21 05:44:39 ns1 kernel: [ 7.476614] systemd[1]: network-pre.target: Found dependency on cloud-init.service/start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just disabled and masked firewalld and went back to IPTables. 
No problems after that.

I had to change fail2ban to work with IPTables by commenting out :

```
# banaction=firewallcmd-ipset
```

in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.d/00-firewalld.conf` - Do not delete the file.

Then I setup a new service to save and restore IPTables on shutdown and reboot as I describe here:

[Running commands on shutdown/restart Ubuntu 18.04](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526729/running-commands-on-shutdown-restart-ubuntu-18-04/526809?noredirect=1#comment974847_526809)

The reason I did not use `iptables-persistent` was because I wanted to integrate IPTables with Webmin which uses `/etc/webmin/firewall/iptables.save` and `/etc/webmin/firewall6/ip6tables.save` as temporary files to edit iptables.

By using my custom service I could use webmin to edit and apply iptables and on shutdown/reboot I saved iptables and restored them back.

Finally I had to add a fix to my service in order to clear out all fail2ban chains and rules, because on reboot f2b would add them again. For this you can follow my solution here:

[REGEX: flush a number of related chains in iptables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526795/regex-flush-a-number-of-related-chains-in-iptables/526812#526812)

Comment: Googling lead me here. Turns out for me it was a problem with firewalld and cloud-init fighting during boot on my AWS EC2 instances. More on this [here](https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.bugs.dist/c/__XqWkuTzxQ?pli=1), [here](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/414), and [here](https://github.com/Xunnamius/supreme/issues/49).