# Running commands on shutdown/restart Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

[My Config] Ubuntu 18.04 - digitalocean droplet/server

[Background] I presume from my research that since 18.04 /etc/network/intefaces has been deprecated and something called netplan was introduced. Desktops get NetworkManager while server-Netplan hands control over to systemd-networkd.

**[Problem]**
Getting a script to run on shutdown/restart. I was planning on using pre-up/post-down in /etc/network/interfaces but this does not work for me due to the reasons stated above.

Specifically the script I want to run has to do with saving and restoring iptables at shutdown and restart.

[iptables-persistent]
Please do not ask me to install iptables-persistent, because even in that case, I would still have to save and restore iptables to a separate file, like a buffer. If  iptables-persistent could somehow save its file in a different location and load that file on restart, I would consider it.

Any ideas?

**[I TRIED]**

1. I created a executable file in /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01firewall
   No result.
   Is this because as stated above NetworkManager is not used in server installs?
2. I created a service in /lib/systemd/system/ with :

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=ipres

   [Service]
   ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/sbin/iptables-save -c > /etc/blah/firewall/up.save'
   ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '/sbin/iptables-save -c > /etc/blah/firewall/down.save'

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

   Partial success since the files are created but are empty (is it because it is too late/early for iptables-save to function?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I used this service definition in file `/etc/systemd/system/ipres.service`:

```
[Unit]
  Description=ipres
  Wants=network-online.target
  After=network.target auditd.service
  ConditionPathExists=/etc/mypath

[Service]
  Type=oneshot
  RemainAfterExit=yes
  ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/my.program load
  ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/my.program save

[Install]
  WantedBy=basic.target
```

and used my.program `/usr/local/bin/my.program` (*chroot rwx*) like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

    case $1 in
    load)
        #Do some stuff
    ;;
    save)
        #Do some stuff
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid action '$1'"
    ;;
    esac
```

Don't forget to start and enable your service.

```
systemctl enable ipres.service && systemctl start ipres.service
```

Works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Does the command work manually on your server and did you enable the service by using:

> systemctl enable < your service name >.service

I have tried your servicefile on ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 with default installation and everything seems to work ;)

Comment: The command works just fine when run manually. However... I get a 0KB file on mine when I reboot the vps.

Comment: Both on ExecStart and ExecStop?

Comment: No, only when I boot up. So it must have been on load. it is all fixed now with the setup I posted in my answer. did you try rebooting? what do u get?

Comment: After a reboot I end up with both files with down: # Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Tue Jun 25 12:29:32 2019 and up: # Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Tue Jun 25 12:27:42 2019

Comment: That's strange. when I rebooted I used to get empty files.