# REGEX: flush a number of related chains in iptables

Tags: bash, scripting, iptables, perl, fail2ban

I want to flush a number of related chains in IPtables. Their names like 'f2b.*'
I want the entire chain gone!
e.g. all this gone.

```
-A f2b-postfix-sasl -s 103.231.139.130/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-postfix-sasl -s 141.98.9.2/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-postfix-sasl -s 45.13.39.56/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-postfix-sasl -s 185.36.81.61/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-postfix-sasl -s 185.36.81.169/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-postfix-sasl -s 185.36.81.165/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-postfix-sasl -s 185.137.111.22/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-postfix-sasl -s 185.137.111.188/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-postfix-sasl -s 185.137.111.123/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-postfix-sasl -j RETURN
-A f2b-ssh-ddos -s 193.201.224.214/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-ssh-ddos -j RETURN
```

Also I would like the chain rules gone:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,115 -j f2b-ssh-ddos
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587,143,993,110,995 -j f2b-postfix-sasl
```

Basically something like this

```
iptables -F .*f2b-.*
iptables -D .*f2b-.*
```

How would you do this?

[Reason] is because I save the iptables on shutdown and restore on reboot. However, fail2ban adds the existing rules again without checking if they already exist. So I end up with duplicates.

**[UPDATE#1]**
I can get the unique chain names like this:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -S | grep -P '\-A f2b-.*' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | sort -u
```

How do I get them deleted without building a loop?

Comment: Do you want to flush entire chain or just remove few rules from any particular chain? Please clarify your question, and give some examples

Comment: Why do you need to save it on reboot? Isn't enough to save base rules one time and load them after reboot and then fail2ban will take care of its own rules?

Comment: Do you know of a way to save rules without the f2b chains and rules, but including all else? currently I just do iptables-save > file and then restore the file.

Comment: I noticed you put a couple "Answer" sections in your Question; if you're trying to self-answer, the answers should go into an Answer box, below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get the unique chain names like this:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -S | grep -P '\-A f2b-.*' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | sort -u
```

How do I get them deleted without building a loop?

**[Answer#1]** Delete all f2b chains

```
/sbin/iptables -S | grep -P '\-A f2b-.*' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | sort -u | awk '{print "/sbin/iptables -F "$1";"}' #| /bin/sh
```

**[Answer#2]** Delete all f2b rules

```
/sbin/iptables -S | grep -P '\-A INPUT.*f2b-.*' | sed 's/^-A //' | awk '{print "/sbin/iptables -D "$0";"}' #| /bin/sh
```

*Note: Uncomment the # when you are ready.*

Answer (score 0):

For your sample case you could do like:

```bash
iptables-save | sed -nE '/^(\*|COMMIT)/p;/^:/s/^:(f2b-[[:graph:]]+).*/-F \1/p;/ -[jg] f2b-[[:graph:]]+/s/^-A/-D/p' | iptables-restore -n
```

This takes `iptables-save`'s output, replaces all chain information instructions (lines starting with `:`) regarding chains `f2b-*` with a respective `-F <chain-name>` command, as well as all `-A` commands referring to `f2b-*` chains with a respective `-D` command, and finally feeds these to `iptables-restore -n`.

It is **important** that you use `-n` option so to make this `iptables-restore` *not* flush everything.

Comment: Thanks for your time my friend much appreciated.